# Jmeter - How to read line by line of CSV data by multiple threads

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am using Jmeter with webdriver sampler. I have a file upload scenario with 10 threads in concurrent. Also there are 3 files to upload.

My scenario is - All the 10 threads first needs to read first line of CSV and upload that file, then all thread read second line and upload second line and next third line and upload third file. How its possible ? Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you set ["Sharing Mode" of the CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) to `Current Thread`

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config Sharing Mode]

If you want the upload to happen at exactly the same moment consider adding [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the request which performs the upload and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to `10`

Demo:

[image: JMeter WebDriver SAmpler Concurrent Upload]